# How to make a bash shell script execute in C?

Tags: c, bash, shell

How might I go about writing a program in C that executes a .sh (shell script) file? I'm writing a program, and one of the functions requires running some shell scripts. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the system function

```
system("myscript.sh");
```